# Tile color, shape, and type detection altogether

Tags: deep-learning, classification, object-detection, yolo, multitask-learning

I'm trying to apply some detections/classification on the set of tiles we have. Specifically, I need to detect color (15 classes), pattern (25 classes- on the surface of tiles, there can be certain patterns, like flower, sun, cloud, ...), and shape of the tiles (10 classes, like circle, rectangle, etc.). Tile images are under different light conditions, night/days, angles, etc. Image below is just a stock image to give you an idea of what tile is!

The problem is due to some resource constraints, we can't have separate models for each and do all classifications within a single model.

How can I achieve this? Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: How would you define a 'model', given that you want to have a single one or a maximum of two? Have you thought about trying a network with a shared backbone and different classification/regression heads for the different tasks you're trying to solve (e.g. similar to Tesla's Hydranet)?

Comment: No I haven't. If you have a lightweight model to do multiple classification, let me know please.